# Restore remote branch to previous commit

Tags: git, repository, remote-branch

By mistake I did few wrong commits. Now I want to restore my `develop` branch to a perticular commit-ID.

I tried

```
$git reset --hard 9f3df1996f435907575acafe922b22b88e6f10c4
HEAD is now at 9f3df19 Merge pull request #1 from txxxx/feature-1
```

This has brought the old repo of this commit to my local repo. But when I try to push this, it gives me an error.

```
$git push origin develop

To https://github.com/txxxxx/XXxxxx.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/txxxxx/XXxxxx.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

I am not sure how to **push these local code** (brought from previous commit) to my `develop` branch now.

Comment: If you want to get rid if those commits on the remote branch, just add a `-f` to the push operation.

Comment: @eftshift0 Can you please help me with full command?

Comment: `git push -f origin develop`

Comment: @eftshift0 Thanks!!

Comment: All seems right, but... `! [rejected]        master -> master` is unexpected here. It should be `develop`, no?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+hint%3A+Updates+were+rejected+because+the+tip+of+your+current+branch+is+behind